# Connect to remote display on Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, ssh, x11-forwarding

So basically, I am **super** lazy, and I want to be able to sit on my couch or in my bed, and watch netflix on my linux desktop or mac mini respectively. I got **super** hyped when I found out about x2x, but I can't find anything like it that will work anymore. Is there any way I can do something like this now with my macbook air.

I have been playing with `ssh -X` and `xterm` and stuff, I just don't see how it's useful. I don't mind getting nitty-gritty with the terminal, I just want to lie in bed while I do it.

Comment: What device is serving the films? What device would you use to see them?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do with the remote display.
Do you want to copy the remote display to a window on your local system (VNC or Xpra would do it) or access remote X11 apps? (Xpra or NX would do that too)